# Is there a name for expressions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^i a_k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

Is there a name for expressions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^i a_k$?

If so, where can I find the equivalent of a Wikipedia entry?

Comment: Every series (with nonzero terms) can be written like that, so no, no special name.